# Error when starting up new installation of Neo4j on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, neo4j

I've downloaded and installed the Neo4j 2.0.1 Community Edition on my Windows 8 64.

I start it up and set a path for the default database. But when it after that tries to start up the server, the following error occurs.

> Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Neo4j Community\db\default

Pulled from messages.log,

> [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@152c108d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Component 'org.neo4j.shell.impl.ShellServerKernelExtension@47df4cd0' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: internal error: ObjID already in use

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you check the server logs if you find some more details? There should be messages.log in your graph database directory and console.log in %APPDATA%\Neo4j Community\logs

Comment: console.log didnt' say anything interesting but there was a error message in messages. I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have some other java application running on your machine?

Or an older version of Neo4j installed as a service?

The error message indicates a conflict of sorts for the Remote Method Invocation registry. 
(if you google for the error message you see that)

Perhaps you can try to run Neo4j in a user account that doesn't have preinstalled or existing software running automatically.

You could also try to use the system tools to find out which app listens on port 1099

Comment: It was another Java application running, WebStorm actually. Does that mean they can't run at the same time though?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a same issue. But now it's resovled.

There is a conflict about tcp port. Other program(in my case sails.js app) already use 1337 tcp port.

So I suggest that you should check it or disable remote shell.(http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell-starting.html)

[image]